# How to run Django migrations inside kubernetes and apply changes to the database pod?

Tags: django, kubernetes

I have deployed my app to Azure with Kubernetes. I have separate pods for front end, back end and database. I encountered problems when one of my database fields changed from `id` to `userId`. I have tried to update this change to my deployment database but without any luck. I logged into my back end pod and removed the existing migration file and run `python manage.py makemigrations` & `python manage.py migrate`. After these I checked that everything was ok in the migration file. After this I don't know what to do. Do I need to remove the database pod and create it again? Or how do I update the database inside the pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id -> userId change is a DDL change for your DB. I suggest that you "exec" into your DB pod and start your DB shell.

```
kubectl exec -it mysql-pod-name bash
```

Then you should be able to execute your DDL statement. MySql example:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
RENAME COLUMN id TO userId;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Would you have some good advices how to automate this process? Or is it even possible?